# XmlMtomReader reading strategy

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xmlreader, mtom

Consider the following code:

```
Stream stream = GetStreamFromSomewhere(); 
XmlDictionaryReader mtomReader =XmlDictionaryReader.CreateMtomReader
(
 stream,
 Encoding.UTF8,
 XmlDictionaryReaderQuoatas.Max
);

/// ...

/// is there best way to read binary data from mtomReader's element??
string elementString = mtomReader.XmlReader.ReadElementString();
byte[] elementBytes = Covert.FromBase64String(elementString);
Stream elementFileStream = new FileStream(tempFileLocation);
elementFileStream.Write(elementBytes,0,elementBytes.Length);
elementFileStream.Close();

/// ...

mtomReader.Close();
```

The problem is that the size of the binary attachment supposed to be over 100Mb sometimes. Is there a way to read element's binary attachment block by block and then write it to the temporary file stream so i can escape from allocating memory for the hole stuff?

The second - even more specific issue - does mtomReader create any internal cache of the mime binary attachment before i read element's content, i.e. allocate memory for binary data? Or does it read bytes from the input stream directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who may be interested in the solution:

```
using (Stream stream = GetStreamFromSomewhere())
{
  using (
    XmlDictionaryReader mtomReader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateMtomReader(
        stream, Encoding.UTF8, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max))
 {
    string elementString = mtomReader.ReadElementString();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    using (
        Stream elementFileStream =
            new FileStream(tempFileLocation, FileMode.Create))
    {
        while(mtomReader.XmlReader.ReadElementContentAsBase64(buffer,0,buffer.Length)
        {
          elementFileStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
    }

    /// ...

    mtomReader.Close();
 }
}
```

ReadElementContentAsBase64(...) helps read binary parts block by block. The second issue of my post was covered perfectly here: [Does XmlMtomReader cache binary data from the input stream internally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503711/does-xmlmtomreader-cache-binary-data-from-the-input-stream-internally)

Answer (score 0):

For an attachment of that size it would be better to use streaming.

> Streamed transfers can improve the
>   scalability of a service by
>   eliminating the requirement for large
>   memory buffers. Whether changing the
>   transfer mode improves scalability
>   depends on the size of the messages
>   being transferred. Large message sizes
>   favor using streamed transfers.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731913.aspx

Comment: Thanks. But that doesn't asnwer my questions either. I'm working with XmlMtomReader, not WCF services.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, your code should be more like this:

```
using (Stream stream = GetStreamFromSomewhere())
{
    using (
        XmlDictionaryReader mtomReader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateMtomReader(
            stream, Encoding.UTF8, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max))
    {
        string elementString = mtomReader.ReadElementString();
        byte[] elementBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(elementString);
        using (
            Stream elementFileStream =
                new FileStream(tempFileLocation, FileMode.Create))
        {
            elementFileStream.Write(
                elementBytes, 0, elementBytes.Length);
        }

        /// ...

        mtomReader.Close();
    }
}
```

Without the `using` blocks, you're at risk of resource leaks.

Comment: I had hoped the answer would be obvious, but it wasn't. I thnink maybe using the `ReadSubTree` method along with reading the content in chunks might help, but I don't know for sure