# Does XmlMtomReader cache binary data from the input stream internally?

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, xmlreader, mtom

Actually i'd like to know if XmlMtomReader reads mime binary parts from the input stream directly? Or does it store them internally before i call ReadContentAsBase64() method?

Comment: I think it would be worth updating the title of the question to reflect the type you're actually interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I recall (and it's been a while...), XmlMtomReader does the minimal amount of internal storage required, depending on the order in which the MIME parts appear in the input stream. (The MTOM standard allows them to appear in any order).

So if your input stream is, for example:

- Binary part 1
- Then the main XML part, e.g.

> < a/ >< b >...binary part 1...< /b >< c >...binary part 2...< /c >< /d >

- Then Binary part 2

Here's what happens:

- To start reading the XML (element "a"), it must store Binary Part 1 internally
- When you read contents of element "b", it comes from the internal storage
- When you start reading element "c", it stores the rest of the XML internally (element "d"), and advances the stream to Binary Part 2. When you read the contents of element "c" at this point, it comes directly from the stream, not from storage.
- When you lastly read element "d", the XML comes from internal storage

Comment: Thank you for the brilliant explanation!!